# Index Match Match Issue - Column Reference Randomly Not Matching

Tags: indexing, excel-formula, match

I am trying to aggregate monthly data by GL code across various company divisions. I am using a an Index Match Match function to bring in the monthly, divisional data and then adding them together (if there is a better solution to do this, then I am open to ideas).

The column reference is by month. However, I am being presented with a #ref error randomly. The error is not consistent with the tab that is causing the issue, etc. An example formula for one of the divisions is:

```
INDEX('Community Programs - Annual'!$D$4:$O$60,MATCH($A29,'Community Programs - Annual'!$A$4:$A$61,0),MATCH(Master!F$3,'Community Programs - Annual'!$D$2:$O$2,0))
```

Data set:

[image: Data set]

Error message:

[image: Error message]

Within the error message, the underlined formula portion is showing a reference of '348' for the column when it should be '3'. This is the month data, so I would assume it would be the most straightforward; however, it is causing a #ref error throughout the workbook.

I made sure all information was the same format, used the trim function for titles, unhid any rows, reviewed the formula, added numbers above the months/used that as a reference. These items did not adjust the outcome.

Comment: Your index is looking from rows 4:60; however, your first match is looking at 4:61, you need these rowsets to match in exact size.